# Why zend_form cannot populate inputs with records from Firebird db with diacritic characters?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, firebird, zend-db

I have zend application connected to Firebird database via ZendX library. It has windows-1250 charset. I am trying to use zend_form to create edit form and populate it with db values. It works with records free of diacritic characters and data is displayed properly, it's editable. Problem occurs whenever there are special characters, and form inputs are empty.

```
 $form->addElement(
                          'textarea',
                          'POD',
                          array(
                            'value' => $this->ksiega['POD'],
                            'attribs' => array( 'class' => 'pod'),
                          )
                        );
                $form->setElementDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Errors'
              ));
```

This shows empty input fields.

```
<textarea name="POD" id="POD" class="pod" rows="24" cols="80"><?=$this->ksiega['POD']?></textarea>
```

This code works.
What am I not aware of here?

Comment: same thing using view form helpers ...

Answer (score 0):

Think problem is that an textarea has no value attribute (?).

You could try:

```
$elem = $form->getElement('POD');
$elem->setValue($this->ksiega['POD']);
```

Comment: Still nothing. $this->formTextarea("ksiegi[".$ksiega['ID']."][POD]", $ksiega['POD']); Same thing with helper. Textarea is empty with special chars, without - filled.

Comment: I've found 

    $this->view->escape($value) 
in Zend_View_Helper_FormTextarea.
Changed to just $value.
It works without escape... Why?

Comment: Ok i think zend is escaping by default when you set an value to the object. Possible some code in your response wich is not allowed and is filtered?